# Use Signal protocol without server

Tags: signal-protocol

I'm trying to establish E2E secured channel with nearby devices (using WiFi direct).
Obviously, I wouldn't like to rely on internet connection. Can I use the signal protocol without a server?

1)Will it be secure to just publish the prekey to the other peer, and after the key-exchange compare the keys' fingerprints?

2) Is it better to compare the fingerprints of the prekey?

3)What hashing method should I use in order to generate keys' fingerprints for comparison? Can I generate a short a pin code or will it be insecure? (I guess it depends on which fingerprints I compare prekes or the actual key).

Comment: One thing is sure: the usual Signal protocols (there are variants) rely on servers to store public keys. So if one removes the server, that's no longer the signal protocol. I closed the question because it does not state the security goals that are targeted, the assumptions made on the participants, and constraints, thus can't be meaningfully answered. If these things where stated, the question could be for crypto-SE or security-SE.

Comment: Your're right, I didn't clarify myself enough. I meant that instead of using a server,  there will be a one time pairing process on which the user is comparing public key fingerprints.



However,  I closed that project of mine so I won't bother to edit the question.